# how to fix and execute this sample Hibernate program for create table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple hibernate program in java. It is throwing an exception and I can't understand.

My code is :

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;

public class TestEmployee {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class);
    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);

}

}
```

The error is :

```
SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x. or 2.0.x
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:197)
        at com.Hibernate.chapter1.TestEmployee.main(TestEmployee.java:10)**
```

Note : There is a line on AnnotationConfiguration() in my eclipse.

What is the cause and How do I fix it?

Comment: replace the slf4j-api 1.6.x jar with slf4j-api 1.5.5 or earlier version

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is given clearly with the error

```
SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x. or 2.0.x
```

An SLF4J binding designates an artifact such as slf4j-jdk14.jar or slf4j-log4j12.jar used to bind slf4j to an underlying logging framework, say, java.util.logging and respectively log4j.
Mixing mixing different versions of slf4j-api.jar and SLF4J binding can cause problems. For example, if you are using slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, then you should also use slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar, using slf4j-simple-1.5.5.jar will not work.

From the client's perspective all versions of slf4j-api are compatible. Client code compiled with slf4j-api-N.jar will run perfectly fine with slf4j-api-M.jar for any N and M. You only need to ensure that the version of your binding matches that of the slf4j-api.jar. You do not have to worry about the version of slf4j-api.jar used by a given dependency in your project. You can always use any version of slf4j-api.jar, and as long as the version of slf4j-api.jar and its binding match, you should be fine.

To make hibernate work you would have added hibernate related jar files to your project. It includes jars whose names start with "slf4j". To fix the error you need to make sure all slf4j jars are of same version.ie ( if you are using slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, then you should also use slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar, using slf4j-simple-1.5.5.jar will not work. )

Updating all your slf4j jars to latest version should fix this or you could check all slf4j jars and replace the offending one.

**The link to download the slf4j is below**

http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

**More about the error and jar can be found at**

http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html

Comment: It hurts a little to have to say this, but you're misinterpreting the very clear error. It states the binding needs to be updated, not the API like you are claiming.

Comment: @Gimby Thnks. my answer was not clear, infact looked incorrect.. It was just poor choice of words. I have rephrased my answer. thanks again for taking the time to comment.